# Mongo repairDatabase procedure

Tags: mongodb, mongo-repair

I need to run a repairDatabase in mongo in order to reclaim some os disk space. Can anyone provide feedback on the following procedure: let me know if its correct, if I'm missing anything, if the steps are in order, etc.

The setup is a primary/secondary on separate servers. They are both about out of disk space. My plan is to repair the database on each one separately after the other completes. As I am out of disk space, I will be using an external block storage from my cloud provider to use as a repair path. Mongo is currently running via sudo service mongodb start. To complete this it seems that I'll run the following:

- On the primary I step down using rs.stepDown()
- I shutdown mongo using rs.shutdownServer() - Is this correct? For the next step it seems that I shouldn't run it if Mongo already has another instance running.
- On the primary I run mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --repair --repairpath PATH_TO_BLOCK_STORAGE
- When complete, do I need to copy the data in the repair path over to the original (/var/lib/mongodb)?
- Once back up, I restart Mongo using sudo service mongodb start
- I then wait for the oplogs to catch up and for the mongos to be in sync.
- Once they primary and secondary are in sync I then go onto mongodb-perf-02 and run rs.stepDown() so that mongodb-perf-01 is the primary again.
- Once complete I then repeat this on the secondary.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this issue was as follows:
Starting with the secondary:

Inside of Mongo I ran the following:

```
db.shutdownServer()
exit
```

On the command line:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*
sudo service mongodb start
```

It then takes a couple of hours to resync. Once resynced I did the following on the primary:

```
rs.status() //To make sure that the everything was synced
rs.stepDown(9200)
db.shutdownServer()
exit
```

On the command line I ran:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*
sudo service mongodb start
```

Then in Mongo I ran:

```
rs.status() //To make sure that everything was synced
rs.freeze(0) //To remove the re.stepDown(9200) lock
```

On the secondary I ran:

```
rs.stepDown()
```

Note: If possible, back up all of your data first.